# Was gold always worthless on Krynn?

Tags: dragonlance

In the *Dragonlance* setting, after the first Cataclysm the most valuable currency is made from steel, and gold is treated as worthless; but was it always so (the part about gold having no value I mean)? Was gold considered a precious metal before the doom of Istar?

Comment: Considering the extensive use of gold for jewelry/ornamentation in Istar [citation needed - no idea which book to dig this up in] it was definitely a precious metal before the Cataclysm.  IIRC, steel has more value post-Cataclysm because gold, being soft, has limited utility (which is also why platinum retained value).  Again, I'm not giving this as an answer because I have no idea which book to look in for quotes; most of those books aren't even mine, they were borrowed.

Comment: @DavidW- yeah but isn't platinum soft too?

Comment: No, platinum is hard enough that it's difficult to work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The original conception of the DRAGONLANCE setting (according to a circa 1985 interview with Tracy Hickman, who was the Dungeon Master for the original campaign) was that before the Cataclysm, the world would have been basically a standard Advanced Dungeons & Dragons setting.  The Cataclysm would explain many of the differences between the DRAGONLANCE campaign—such as how the halflings, dwarves, and gnomes became the kender, gully dwarves, and tinker gnomes; how the dragons ceased to be commonplace monsters; and how the currency changed.  The implication was that before the Cataclysm, the world would have used the standard AD&D currency system.

Things drifted away from this idea once the setting became extremely popular and especially as the novels overtook the gaming products as the principal sources for describing the world.  However, in the Tales Volume II (*The Cataclysm*)—which was the first source I was aware of that described the pre-Cataclysm world in detail—the various authors did depict an economic system based on gold and silver coinages.

Comment: Just as a point of interest, I asked Margaret Weis and this was her response about Steel coins: https://twitter.com/WeisMargaret/status/1382726400529010689 Obviously a limited response, but it seems to indicate Steel currency was in use during the campaign.